# Listing files older than x minutes/hours in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that I want to list all my files older than x hours. But I have some errors. What would be the correct syntax?!

`find: missing argument to`-exec'

`./script.sh: line 9: [[0: command not found [root@localhost home]#`

````
prev_count=0
path=/home/alex/

find $path -type f -mmin +2 -exec ls -ltrh\; > /home/test.txt
count=$(cat /home/test.txt | wc -l)

if ["$prev_count" -lt "$count"]
then
echo "This are the files that need to be deleted" >> $MESSAGE
echo "+----------------------------------------+" >> $MESSAGE
echo "" >> $MESSAGE
fi```
````

Comment: try https://shellcheck.net  to validate your script.

Comment: IMHO experts advice to check your shell code in https://shellcheck.net once for syntax errors, request you to please check this there once.

Comment: The `\;` should be separated by a white space from any command.

Comment: Thx for the help guys. I managed to find  a solution.